# Confusion about file counting

Tags: perl

I've seen numerous posts about using Perl to count specific files in a directory, one of which showed this code

```
@filesInDirectory = glob("$directory$fileNameRegex");
$numberOfFiles = @filesInDirectory;
```

Then if I follow this with:

```
print LOGFILE $#filesInDirectory;
print LOGFILE $numberOfFiles;
```

The log will have 01.  Where the confusion is this:  Why is $numberOfFiles 1 instead of 0 when the file I'm looking for doesn't exist?

Comment: Show us full code please, including the contents of the directory you are counting.

Comment: $# is the last index in the array, whereas using an array in scalar context $numberOfFiles contains the number of elements in the array

Comment: Thanks Stan, I knew what $# did, but I did not realize $numberOfFiles was different by holding the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filename globs are not regular expressions, so if `$fileNameRegex` is what its name implies, it's the wrong thing to use here.

Globs are the pattern-matching language you use to expand filenames into a shell command line: `*` matches any string of characters (equivalent to `.*` in a regular expression), `?` matches a single character (equivalent to `.` in a regular expression), and `[]` works pretty much the same as in regular expressions.

If you need to test filenames against a regular expression, you'll have to do a `grep` on the list you get back from `glob` (or `readdir`).

Comment: In my case, $fileNameRegex is an actual file name, such as myFile.txt

Comment: In that case, another aspect of globbing is relevant: when there are no matches, `glob` returns the string as is. Maybe you have no matches because there's no slash between your directory and your filename

Comment: I had an idea that glob might be doing that but just didn't know for sure.  Apparently my inexperience with glob is the cause of my confusion.  Thanks for clearing this up for me.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley When there are no matches, `glob` returns an empty list.

Comment: @MattJacob: apparently so... if the argument actually contains any wildcard characters. `glob("foo")` returns foo though, regardless of whether `foo` exists.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley In scalar context. This is list context.

Comment: @MattJacob: `perl -le 'print for glob("foo")'` prints `foo` for me, in version 5.22.0 and 5.14.2

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley I think you're right, but it looks like that only happens if there aren't any wildcards in the search pattern.

Answer (score 10):

`$numberOfFiles` contains the numbers of elements `@filesInDirectory`. Since `@filesInDirectory` contains one element, `$numberOfFiles` contains `1`.

`$#filesInDirectory` contains the index of the last element in `@filesInDirectory`. Since `@filesInDirectory` contains one element (`$filesInDirectory[0]`), `$numberOfFiles` contains `0`.

Unless you mess with `$[` (don't!!), `$#a` will always be one less than `@a` in scalar context.

Answer (score 2):

If you're wondering why `@filesInDirectory` has something in it instead of being empty, then you already have [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34617833/622310)

But if you're asking why `$numberOfFiles` is different from `$#filesInDirectory` then it's because the first contains the number of elements in `@filesInDirectory` while the second contains the *index of the last element* of `@filesInDirectory`

Perl indices start at zero, so if `@array` has exactly one element then `$#array` will be zero. If `@array` is empty then `$#array` will be -1